# Accessing AppEngine's <version>-string from GWT

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Is it possible in GWT to programmatically read out the `<version>` string from `appengine-web.xml`?

Might be tough, since GWT doesn't really depend on AppEngine, but I thought I'd ask. I've been given great solutions here before for more obscure things... :)

Answer (score 1):

GWT compiles to JavaScript which runs in the browser. It knows nothing about the backend, which may not even exist.

You can make a call from your client to the backend and ask for a version.

Comment: Right, but the GWT compiler is quite flexible, so I wouldn't be surprised if someone had written some annotation processor or deferred binding plugin or whatever for it to read out the version from the file. Seems like a use-case that could come up somewhat often, given that GWT and AppEngine were initially sort-of released together as a package by Google.